# invalid data is getting inserted in table in sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I faced a situation and also searched for it in the internet but could not be able to get any solution.

**Problem**

My sql server table has 15000 records. It has several columns.

Among all the records, the **'Email ID'** column of **one record** is storing value along with an unidentified character at the beginning. (Please refer to picture attached)

[image]

**What I want**

I want to get rid of that character using sql query. I am using sql server 2012 version.
I tried with 'replace()' and 'patindex()'. I even tried 'stuff' function.
But, its not working. Instead, when I am fetching the data using query, it is showing that typical character.

Please help me with some ideas. If I need to do some settings in database or table, I am ready for that.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the datatype of column?

Comment: Varchar(100). I am getting the character by using: "select nchar(UNICODE('cashilpajain05@gmail.com')". You can also try it in your query window. I hope you will also get the same. I also used "replace()" on it...but its not getting replaced.

Comment: Can you try to copy the input data into a text editor and check what is the character?

Comment: @shree.pat18 - I was wrong. I can be able to replace the character using "replace()". I tried to copy the data to input editor but its not showing there. Anyways, it got replaced. So, now I think I can be able to manage the situation. Thanks a lot man.